# How to send String[] imageUrl to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am having array of image URL.On button click I want to send selected image URL to another activity.

**Main.java**

```
String[] imageUrl={"https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/contact/images/technical-icon.png","https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/contact/images/technical-icon.png", "https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/contact/images/technical-icon.png"};

 Button btnNextScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNextScreen);
        btnNextScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {

                Uri uri = Uri.parse("******");
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                            startActivity(intent)



            }           
        });
```

**OpenImage.java**

ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);

What to write here next

Comment: You can use putExtra in intent.

Comment: i have already tried this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your First Activity,

```
String[] data = {"Hello", "World"};
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("some_key", data);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in you Sencon Activity,

```
// At class level
private static final String TAG = SecondActivity.class.getSimpleName();

// In onCreate
String[] data = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("some_key");
for (String x : data) {
    Log.i(TAG, x);  
    // Toast to display all you values one by one
    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
}
```

Hope this helps...:)

Comment: please can u tell me what is TAG in second activity?? because i am new to android..sorry for basic question

Comment: TAG is a common convention in android LogCat machenisim, which is supposed to be the key against you log...Normally it is a class level declaration which have name of class, or anything else you want to make your log distinct in LogCat.

Comment: thnx..i tried your code but i am getting blank page on button click

Comment: Check the logcat to see results...or you can also use toast instead of  logs to see results on screen...let me update anser with Toast example...

Comment: by using toast i am getting url of selected image but no image and in logcat 111-12 07:27:26.794: I/OpenImage(2130): x=https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/contact/images/technical-icon.png

how to display image??

Comment: Oh dear...you question was "How to send String[] imageUrl to another activity"...so my answer is only providing the way of passing String array to next activity, and now...you have get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Bundle bundel = new Bundle();
bundel.putStringArray("key",array);

Intent intent = new Intent(this,next.class)
intent.putExtras(bundel);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: please can u tell me what to write in another activity?

Comment: Use this in your 2nd activity: String[] data = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("key");

Answer (score 0):

or just

intent.putExtra("strings", myStrings);

the putExtra has many overloads, pass array of primitive type is one of them :)

Answer (score 0):

Use This ti send another Activity...

```
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putStringArray("ArrayURL", imageUrl);
        intent1.putExtras(bundle);
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent1);
```

and For Getting

```
    Bundle b = getArguments();
    Cat_Name = b.getStringArray("ArrayURL");
```